# grequests not working with django

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, gevent

I have a Django project that uses Grequests, When I run:
python manage.py runserver, everything is working fine, however when I upload the project to a server

(following this toutorial:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04)

and try to run it on Apache with mod_wsgi,
I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/event.py", line 294, in _notify_links
error: cannot switch to a different thread
(,
 ) failed with error

ERROR!: At 'base_api_handler.create_object':
ERROR:root:ERROR!: At 'base_api_handler.create_object':
This operation would block forever
ERROR!: At 'base_api_handler.create_object':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/event.py", line 294, in _notify_links
error: cannot switch to a different thread
(,
 ) failed with error

ERROR:root: Error: This operation would block forever

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use mod_wsgi with gevent (which grequests uses).

Comment: but way is that? and what is the alternative?

Comment: @Maxim Were you able to resolve the issue ? in my case I ended up removing the greqeusts library.